# Get Element inside Array With Django-MongoDB (Djongo)

Tags: python, django, mongodb, djongo

I am using Django with MongoDB as my database. I create a model (MyObject) and one field is an ArrayField type that contains in which entry JSON Fields. For that I created an abstract model.

So my models.py:

```
class MyObject(models.Model):
    ...
    myArrayField = models.ArrayField(model_container=NIC, null=True, blank=True, default=[])
    ...

class MyAbstractObject(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=100, default="")
    field2 = models.IPAddressField(blank=True, null=True, default="")
    
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

In mongoDB I have:

```
MyObject:
{
   ...
   myArrayField: [{field1: "abc", field2: "1.1.1.1"}]
   ...
}
```

Now I want to get the element that have the value "1.1.1.1", how can I do that?

I try:

```
q1 = MyObject.objects.filter(myArrayField__contains='1.1.1.1')
q2 = MyObject.objects.filter(myArrayField_0_field2='1.1.1.1')
q3 = MyObject.objects.filter(myArrayField__contains={'field2':'1.1.1.1})
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

The [Djongo Doc](https://www.djongomapper.com/using-django-with-mongodb-array-field/#querying-array-fields) makes querying an `ArrayField` very clear, here's an example from the doc:

```
entries = Entry.objects.filter(authors={'name': 'Paul'})
```

which in your case will be something like:

```
q1 = MyObject.objects.filter(myArrayField={'field2'='1.1.1.1'})
```

take a look at the [doc](https://www.djongomapper.com/using-django-with-mongodb-array-field/#querying-array-fields) for more complex querying